# How to prove this?.

Tags: complex-analysis

let $f:D\to D$ be a holomorphic function on the unity disk $D$.

If $f(0)=0$, prove that $|f'(0)|\le1$.

Comment: try to make the title of the question useful for people looking for something similar.

Comment: [See this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma).

Answer (score 3):

This result (or variants of it) is usually called the Schwarz Lemma. The proof uses the Maximum Modulus Principle. The trick is to define an auxillary function:
$$g(z)=\begin{cases}\frac{f(z)}{z}& z\neq 0\\ f'(0)&z=0\end{cases}$$
First show that this function is holomorphic. Then apply the maximum modulus principle and see what happens.

Comment: but the unity disk is open so that  we can not apply the Maximum Modulus Principle on the unity circle